# Understanding Mysql 'on duplicate key'

Tags: php, mysql, insert, edit

```
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas (nombre,urlimagen,id_usuario) values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
```

I want to avoid what i do tipically

- SELECT if exists
- If exists

  - Update
- Else

  - Insert

Questions, will the sentence i wrote do that? The way i see it, if i call

```
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas ('casa','image.png',2) 
                      values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
           on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas ('casa','image2.png',2) 
                       values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
           on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
```

Result will be two elements in table with 'casa' name, right? (instead of editing urlimagen. becaus it will be considred different elements, right)

how could i do to, by one mysql sentence, update urlimagen (for nombre,iduser combination) and if no exists, insert it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe replace will help you ? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: It's impossible to know: it depends on your table keys. Also, you should install HeidiSQL or any other MySQL client and test your SQL code there. SQL can be difficult to debug if all you see is the PHP code that generates it rather than the code itself.

Comment: Primary key is id (autoincrement), no other keys

Answer (score 1):

the `update urlimagen = values('$ruta')` is telling MySql to look for a column named the **value** of `$ruta`. Change your statement to use the **actual column name**:

```
insert into mapa_etiquetas (nombre, urlimagen, id_usuario)
  values ('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u'),
    ('$this->nombre', '$ruta2', '$u')
    /*Add more rows here*/
  on duplicate key update
    urlimagen = values(urlimagen)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query doesn't match your second code block.

**First**

```
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas (nombre,urlimagen,id_usuario)
    values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
    on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
```

**Second:Incorrect**

```
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas ('casa','image.png',2) 
                  values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
       on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas ('casa','image2.png',2) 
                   values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
       on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
```

The problem with your second block is that you are naming values where the column names should go.  I believe the correct second block should be:

**Second:Corrected**

```
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas (nombre,urlimagen,id_usuario) 
                  values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
       on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
$update = "insert into mapa_etiquetas (nombre,urlimagen,id_usuario) 
                   values('$this->nombre', '$ruta', '$u') 
       on duplicate key update urlimagen=values('$ruta')";
```

I also agree with @The Scrum Meister.  Their answer should be heeded regarding appropriate use of the 'on duplicate key update' clause.